# Combine ha-mode with queue-master-locator in a RabbitMQ cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, high-availability, rabbitmqctl

In a RabbitMQ cluster, I know that the queues can be created with their masters on different nodes, using the "min-masters" strategy of the "queue_master_locator" policy. This would mean that the queues are no longer mirrored(ha-mode policy cant be applied), as only one policy can be applied at a time. Is there a way to accomplish both? 
I basically want to have the queues distributed across cluster nodes, so the memory footprint on a single node is reduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`queue_master_locator=min-masters` policy means that the master queue node is automatically assigned using the rabbitmq node with less masters.

This is not related to ha-mirror policy.

you have 3 ways to solve the problem:

1. create  a single policy with both the features in this way:[image]
2. create only the ha policy and add the arg `x-queue-master-locator` to each single queue:
   [image]
3. create only the ha policy and use the rabbitmq config file to define the `x-queue-master-locator`, see here for more details: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-file

Also suggesto to read this [blog post](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/take-control-of-your-rabbitmq-queues.html) about that.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, I went ahead with the third approach, and it seems to work as expected